# Proving determinant for orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

If there are two matrices $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ such that $\det(A)+det(B)=0$, where both the matrices are real orthogonal matrices.

How can I say the following?

$\det(A+B) = \det(A^T(A+B)B^T)$

Is it a simple property of orthogonal matrices?

Comment: You don't seem to need $\text{det}(A) + \text{det}(B) = 0$ for this. It comes down to some simple algebraic manipulations: Reduce the expression $\text{det}(A^T(A+B)B^T)$ using that $A^TA=I$ for an orthogonal matrix, and that $\text{det}(A)=\text{det}(A^T)$ for any matrix; and that $(A+B)^T = A^T + B^T$ for any matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yes I saw the mistake I made in my calculations. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is orthogonal if $AA^T=A^TA=I$. So
\begin{align*}
\det(A^T(A+B)B^T)&=\det(A^TAB^T+A^TBB^T)\\
&=\det(IB^T+A^TI)\\
&=\det(B^T+A^T)\\
&=\det(B+A)^T.
\end{align*}
But the determinant of a matrix and it's transpose are equal, so this is also equal to $\det(A+B)$.